# Logistic Regression in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocamlfind

I was trying to use Logistic regression in OCaml. I need to use it as a blackbox for another problem I'm solving. I found the following site:

http://math.umons.ac.be/anum/en/software/OCaml/Logistic_Regression/

I pasted the following code (with a few modifications - I defined my own iris_features and iris_label) from this site into a file named logistic_regression.ml:

```
open Scanf
open Format
open Bigarray
open Lacaml.D

let log_reg ?(lambda=0.1) x y =
  (* [f_df] returns the value of the function to maximize and store
     its gradient in [g]. *)
  let f_df w g =
    let s = ref 0. in
    ignore(copy ~y:g w); (* g ← w *)
    scal (-. lambda) g;  (* g = -λ w *)
    for i = 0 to Array.length x - 1 do
      let yi = float y.(i) in
      let e = exp(-. yi *. dot w x.(i)) in
      s := !s +. log1p e;
      axpy g ~alpha:(yi *. e /. (1. +. e)) ~x:x.(i);
    done;
    -. !s -. 0.5 *. lambda *. dot w w
  in
  let w = Vec.make0 (Vec.dim x.(0)) in
  ignore(Lbfgs.F.max f_df w);
  w


let iris_features = [1 ; 2 ; 3] ;;
let iris_labels = 2 ;;

let proba w x y = 1. /. (1. +. exp(-. float y *. dot w x))
let () =
  let sol = log_reg iris_features iris_labels in
  printf "w = %a\n" Lacaml.Io.pp_fvec sol;
  let nwrongs = ref 0 in
  for i = 0 to Array.length iris_features - 1 do
    let p = proba sol iris_features.(i) iris_labels.(i) in
    printf "Label = %i prob = %g => %s\n" iris_labels.(i) p
      (if p > 0.5 then "correct" else (incr nwrongs; "wrong"))
  done;
  printf "Number of wrong labels: %i\n" !nwrongs
```

I have the following questions:

1. On trying to compile the code, I get the error message: "`Error: Unbound module Lacaml`". I've installed Lacaml; done opam init several times, tried to provide a flag -package = Lacaml ; I don't know how to solve this?
2. As you can see I've defined my own version of iris_features and iris_labels - are the types correct i.e. in the function log_reg is the type of x  int list and that of y as int?

Comment: Can't dig into this one too much right now, but I note that you're passing `iris_features` to `Array.length` but that function expects an array, rather than a list. You could bind `iris_features` to an equivalent array using the literal `[|1; 2; 3|]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `iris_features` and `iris_labels` are arrays and array literals in OCaml are delimited with the `[|`, `|]` style parentheses, e.g.,

```
let iris_features = [|(* I don't know what to put here*)|]
let iris_labels = [|2|]
```

The `iris_features` array has type `vec array`, i.e., an array of vectors, not an array of integers, and didn't I dig too deep to know what to put there, but the syntax is the following,

```
let iris_features =[|
  Vec.of_list [1.; 2.; 3.;];
  Vec.of_list [4.; 5.; 6.;];
|]
```

The Lacaml interface has changed a bit since the code was written and `axpy` no longer accepts labeled `~x` arguments (both x and y vectors are positional now) so you need to remove `~x` and fix the order (I presume that `x.(i)` is `x` in the `a*x + y` expression and `g` corresponds to `y`, e.g.,

```
 axpy ~alpha:(yi *. e /. (1. +. e)) x.(i) g;
```

This code also depends on `lbfgs`, so you need to install it as well,

```
opam depext --install lbfgs
```

I would suggest you using [dune](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as your default built system but for fast prototyping, you can use `ocamlbuild`. Put your code into an empty folder in a file named `regress.ml` (you can pick other name, just update the build instructions correspondingly), now you can build it to a native executable, as

```
ocamlbuild -pkg lacaml -pkg lbfgs regress.native
```

run it as

```
./regress.native
```

If you're playing in the OCaml toplevel (aka interpreter, i.e., running your code in the `ocaml` interpreter), you can load `lacaml` and `lbfgs` using the following two directives:

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "lacaml.top";;
#require "lbfgs";;
```

(The `#` is not a prompt but a part of the directive syntax, so don't forget to type it as well).

Now you can copy-paste your code into the interpreter and play with it.

## Bonus Track - building with dune

1. create an empty folder and a put `regress.ml` there.
2. remove `open Bigarray` and `open Scanf` as dune is very strict on warnings and turns them into errors (and it will warn you on those lines as they are, in fact, unused)
3. create the dune project

```
dune init exe regress --libs lacaml,lbfgs
```

4. build and run

```
dune exec ./regress.exe
```